# pass along the values of checkboxes

Tags: jquery

i have the following checboxes:

```
<section class="col col-12">
    <label class="input">Templates</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Status" class="Status" value="'Listing Task'" id="Status1" title="445" checked>&nbsp; Listing Task
    <br> 

    <input type="checkbox" name="Status" class="Status" value="'Pending Task'" id="Status2" title="445" >&nbsp; Pending Task
    <br> 

    <input type="checkbox" name="Status" class="Status" value="'Test Template'" id="Status3" title="445" >&nbsp; Test Template
    <br> 

</section>
```

when i get the value of the checkboxes, i am doing form.serialize() which is bringing in the checkboxes value:

the value is coming as:

```
Status='Listing+Task'&Status='Test+Template'
```

I want it to be like: `'Listing Task','Test Template'`

Comment: use `name="Status[]"`

Comment: form.serialize() formats the data for use in a URL. If you want another formatting, then do it yourself or find a library that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Form.serialise](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) converts a form into a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) for processing by a URL. It's typically used to send an ajax request with the data in a URL hence using the query string format.

In your case, you'd be better off processing the elements as a JQuery collection and building the corrected formatted list manually, like this:

```
var list = ''

var processListElem = function() {
  list += $(this).val() + ',';    
}

$('.Status').each(processListElem);
```

Where `each()` takes all the elements in a set (in this case all `.Status` elements) and performs the action in a function `processListElem` on them.

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjkw1gy8/6/) for a working example.

PS, I expect you want logic for removing the last comma and responding to the checked state of the checkboxes but I wanted to isolate the precise problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the value from all inputs whenever you need it:

```
var list = '';
$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
    if(this.checked){
        list += (list == '' ? '' : ', ') + $(this).val();
    }
 });
alert(list);
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/h55g98r2/6/)